# I get an error on one host, not on other

Tags: php, xml

Sadly, one plugin is causing me problems. It works great on one website but gives me an error on another website. 
this is the error:
simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:      http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197971691194/?xml=1:1: parser error : Document is   empty

XenForo_Application::handlePhpError() in Steam/ControllerPublic/Register.php at line 117

If I go there, this is the code:

```
// Get User Profile Data
$id = $session->get('steam_id');
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{id}/?xml=1");
if(!empty($xml)) {
$username = $xml->steamID;
$avatar = $xml->avatarFull;
```

The link is valid, you can try yourself and let's say go here: steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197971691194 or http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198041253738

Really need help, this is the only thing that is blocking me from starting the website!

Answer (score 2):

That probably means that your host is blocking outbound HTTP requests.
Ask them to stop that, or find a better host.